# How to set important features as attribute on XGBRegressor and save as part of json while saving the model

Tags: python, python-3.x, xgboost, xgbregressor

I have trained a `XGBRegressor` model. Now, I am trying to save the important features as attribute on the model and want that the attribute gets saved/restored along with the model.

I have 2 issues here -

1.

```
regressor.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train, eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_validation, y_validation)], verbose=False)

feature_importance: List[Tuple[str, float]] = sorted(
            regressor.get_booster().get_score(importance_type="gain").items(), key=lambda x: x[1]
        )
selected_features: List[str] = [x[0] for x in feature_importance if x[1] > 0]
setattr(regressor, "selected_features", selected_features)
```

The `setattr` and corresponding `getattr` is giving me lint warnings (B010 and B009) - is there better way to do this to avoid those warnings?

The getattr usage is something like this -

```
def get_model_features(model: XGBRegressor) -> List[str] | None:
   return getattr(model, "selected_features") if (model is not None and isinstance(model, XGBRegressor) else None
```

2. The attribute does not get saved in the json file. I am using following call to save -

`regressor.save_model(fname="model.json")`

How to accomplish this? I want to avoid pickle save/restore.

Comment: The `setattr` can be replaced with `regressor.selected_features = selected_features`. Where's the "corresponding `getattr`"?

Comment: it's in another function - I'm updating the original post to show example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The attribute does not get saved in the json file

This is the expected behaviour.

The `XGBRegressor.save_model(fname)` method call simply "redirects" to the [`Booster.save_model(fname)`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.save_model) method call. Any attributes that were defined in the top-most Scikit-Learn layer (such as custom feature importance attributes) **will not** be propagated along.

The underlying XGBoost model saver/loader (via JSON/UBJSON) does not contain any logic for maintaining custom model metadata. Ony real model data, which is actually used by XGBoost itself.

If you want to save Scikit-Learn wrappers with custom attributes, then you must keep using the pickle data format. No way around there.

Comment: What I'm trying now is to save the model as json. Load the json file back and append additional attribute in memory json data and save the json back with same file name. While loading, I load the json and extract only the model part as json_data["model"] - is there a way to directly construct XGBRegressor from this in-memory data? Or do I have to save it as temporary json and load it back? I have tried converting this json_data[model] to str using json.dumps() and tried passing that to load_model(fp=json_model_str) but it gives me an exception saying "File name too long".

Comment: You should dump your modified JSON content to a file in a local filesystem, and then load it using the `load_model(path)` function. Right now, as evident from the stated error message, you appear to be passing the JSON content (hundreds of thousands characters) in place of a file name (say, hundred characters).

Comment: But your general direction is correct. The Booster JSON object has a `attributes` section (that is a map of string keys to string values), which you can fill with your own key-value pairs. However, there is no official Scikit-Learn API for doing that, so you must find your own way.

Comment: Thanks. The load_model() api takes file/str/bytes - I interpreted str to be like json (as in load_model with file it must be internally loading json and using that to initialize the regressor internally) but it seems my understanding was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Based on inputs from @user1808924 and input from a fellow colleague, I finally did something similar to following:

```
regressor.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train, eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_validation, y_validation)], verbose=False)

feature_importance: List[Tuple[str, float]] = sorted(
            regressor.get_booster().get_score(importance_type="gain").items(), key=lambda x: x[1]
        )
selected_features: List[str] = [x[0] for x in feature_importance if x[1] > 0]

model_data: Dict[str, Any] = {
    "model": base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(regressor)).decode('utf-8'),
    "features": selected_features,
}


with open('XGBModel.json', 'w') as json_file: 
    json.dump(model_data, json_file)
```